# Azure cli running batch azure devops error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I get this error when using azure cli with multiple lines. Single commands are working fine.

```
The term 'call' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, what's result if you change the script type to batch like Bevan suggests? Please check if his answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just created a new release and replicated the behavior. You actually have `Powershell` selected in the `Script Type` field. Change it to `Batch` and it will work as expected.

**EDIT**

I thought I'd also share how to run Batch scripts from your repo and not worry if the dev has a `call`  statement at the start of each line. I simply have a standardise script in my build which injects `call` before publishing the artifact

```
$Deploy_File = Get-Item "Azure-Commands.cmd"
$Deploy_File_Script = $Deploy_File | Get-Content

$Deploy_File_Script_Mod = @()

##Standardise commands for Azure CLI Deployment task
# Loop through Commands
foreach ($Command in $Deploy_File_Script) {
    #Insert "CALL" before each azure command
    if ($Command -like "az *") {
        $Command = "call " + $Command
    }

    # Build Modified script array
    $Deploy_File_Script_Mod += "$Command"
}

#Save to file
$Deploy_File | Set-Content -Value $Deploy_File_Script_Mod

#Output modified commands in file
$Deploy_File | Get-Content
```

Now you can just call the standardised deploy file from the task above